# How do I round inprecise floating point addition in PHP?

Tags: php, floating-point, php-7

When adding floats I'm getting consistent inconsistencies. I'm aware that
floats are not accurate - but how do I add 1.95 to 1.95 and end up with 3.9
instead of 3.89999999? Rounding does not work. number_format can fix the final
result but not during the addition.

```
$amountPaid = 0;
var_export($amountPaid); echo "<br>\n";
$amountPaid = $amountPaid + 1.95;
var_export($amountPaid); echo "<br>\n";
$amountPaid = $amountPaid + 1.95;
var_export($amountPaid); echo "<br>\n";
$amountPaid = $amountPaid + 1.95;
var_export($amountPaid); echo "<br>\n";
$amountPaid = $amountPaid + 1.95;
var_export($amountPaid); echo "<br>\n";
$amountPaid = $amountPaid + 1.95;
var_export($amountPaid); echo "<br>\n";
$amountPaid = $amountPaid + 1.95;
var_export($amountPaid); echo "<br>\n";

echo '<h1>Rounding does not work</h1>';
var_export(round($amountPaid,1)); echo "<br>\n";
```

This is the output:

```
0
1.95
3.8999999999999999
5.8499999999999996
7.7999999999999998
9.75
11.699999999999999
Rounding does not work
11.699999999999999
```

I've also tried rounding at every step, using `number_format` (but that returns a string) and using the `$amountPaid +=` syntax.

Comment: Think about using `var_dump` instead of `var_export` if you want to get the correct result of rounded values

Comment: Don't round at every stage; only round at the very end, when you need to display the value, otherwise you're actually increasing the error at every stage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is `var_export`

> Looks like since version 5.4.22 var_export uses the
>   serialize_precision ini setting, rather than the precision one used
>   for normal output of floating-point numbers. As a consequence since
>   version 5.4.22 for example var_export(1.1) will output
>   1.1000000000000001 (17 is default precision value) and not 1.1 as before.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.var-export.php#113770

In addition to that I should mention, that the `serialize_precision` [setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.serialize-precision) changed to `-1` in PHP 7.1 and your code works just fine.

So instead of using `var_export`, just use `echo` for printing the value or `var_dump` to dump the value.

In most cases your code will just work fine, if you do your calculations and just round the value if you print it. If you need a bigger accuracy, you should work with big number libraries like [bc math](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php). They aren't as fast as IEEE numbers, but don't have rounding problems like this.

Comment: Ah! In which case the issue is actually `fputcsv` where the value finally gets output - my use of var_export to debug was sending me in all the wrong directions.

I've wrapped the value in `number_format` before passing it to `fputcsv` and that's solved the problem. Thanks!